# Possible bug in Chrome when using CSS perspective

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am using the following code to change `rotateY` of an element when user click a button.

The `div` wrapper use `perspective` CSS property to create a 3D alike effect.

The issue I am facing is on **Chrome** only, currently I am testing on version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit).

Basically when the button is pressed and the inline CSS is changes the `perspective` effect is not applied.
In order to have applied this effect user need to resize browser window or the code should replace with same value `perspective` on the wrapping `div`.

On `Firefox 50.1.0` the problem does not exist and when user slick button the `div` has right perspective applied.

I would like to know:

- If you have the same issue in your browser.
- If is a known bug on Chrome or a problem with my code.
- If you know any work around or fix.

Notes:
- I have the limitation to apply all CSS inline as I cannot toggle CSS classes.

```js
var target = document.querySelector('#target');
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  target.style.transform = 'rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1)';
});
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">Change rotation</button>
<div id="box-6o80mut6" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 250px; perspective: 250px; z-index: 0;">
  <div id="target" style="position: inherit; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 304px; height: 204px; transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1); border-radius: 10px; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(82, 165, 255); border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 1; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039) 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edited - Same issue. FF works fine.

Comment: Same issue here, if the element is inspected, it actually shows the contours of the right shape, very strange. https://i.imgur.com/bfEF6cg.png

Answer (score 1):

For my understand it looks like a browser's bug. Currently I am using the following work around to solve this issue.
The hack consists in forcing the DOM redraw/refresh toggling a class with  pseudo element as:
  
 `.force-redraw::before {
      content: ""
    }`

The bug seems related to DOM redraw/refresh so it must be forced manually.

Still if you know a better way or a proper fix, please post your answer.

```js
var target = document.querySelector('#target');
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  target.classList.toggle('force-redraw');
  target.style.transform = 'rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1)';
});
```

```css
.force-redraw::before {
  content: ""
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">Rotate me</button>
Try it Yourself »
<div id="wrapper" style="position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 250px; width: 304px; height: 204px; perspective: 1000px; z-index: 0;">
  <div id="target" style="position: inherit; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: inherit; height: inherit; transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1); border-radius: 10px;  background-color: rgb(82, 165, 255);">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work if you split the styles out from the inline elements:

```js
var target = document.querySelector('#target');
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  target.style.transform = 'rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1)';
});
```

```css
#box-6o80mut6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 25px;
  perspective: 250px;
  z-index: 0;
}
#target {
  position: inherit;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 304px;
  height: 204px;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(82, 165, 255);
  border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  perspective: 250px;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">Change rotation</button>
<div id="box-6o80mut6">
  <div id="target">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you problem with `height`:

```js
var target = document.querySelector('#target');
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  target.style.height = "300px";
  target.style.transform = 'rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1)';
});
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">Change rotation</button>
<div id="box-6o80mut6" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 250px; perspective: 250px; z-index: 0;">
  <div id="target" style="position: inherit; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 304px; height: 204px; transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1); border-radius: 10px; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(82, 165, 255); border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 1; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039) 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When applying styles I believe it's a better practice to assign these styles to classes and simply using JS to toggle the classes.

This way it's much cleaner, and works as expected.

```js
var target = document.querySelector('#target');
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  target.classList.add('myclass');
});
```

```css
.original {
position: inherit; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 304px; height: 204px; transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1); border-radius: 10px; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(82, 165, 255); border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 1; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039) 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.myclass {
transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);}
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">Change rotation</button>
<div id="box-6o80mut6" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 250px; perspective: 250px; z-index: 0;">
  <div id="target" class="original">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my specific case I need to change inline and I cannot toggle classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have an explanation, but I already faced some similar issue with chrome (but it wasn't because of inlined styles).

The workaround is to force the browser to re-render after the transformation occured :

```js
var target = document.querySelector('#target');
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  target.style.transform = 'rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1)';
  target.style.borderColor = 'transparent';
// this forces a repaint, not visible
  target.offsetWidth;
  target.style.borderColor = 'black';
});
```

```html
<button id="btn" type="button">Change rotation</button>
<div id="box-6o80mut6" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 250px; perspective: 250px; z-index: 0;">
  <div id="target" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 304px; height: 204px; transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg) skewY(0deg) skewX(0deg) scaleX(1) scaleY(1); border-radius: 10px; border-style: solid; border-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(82, 165, 255); border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 1; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039) 0px 0px 0px 0px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your time on this issue, I got you point, but unfortunately I can use online inline CSS, I tried to follow your advice and replace `inherit` with `absolute` and I still experience the same issue, you can have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/wdwdyb3j/

Comment: @GibboK, I didn't thought it could be linked to inlined styles vs in `<style>` element... Anyway, I edited with an other workaround than yours.